# vba in excel 2003

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to understand this code, and I still don't know why it starts with 2 on the cell A1, shouldn't it start with 1?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
For j = 1 To 5
Cells(i, j).Value = i + j
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

because on my other example I have this and it starts with 1 in A1:

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To 10
  Cells(i, 1).Value = i
  Next
  End Sub
```

Thanks :-) will greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first example you have two for-loops, one nested in another. You basically form a 2D array, with the value of each cell being the sum of the row and column index.

At the second example you have a 1D array.

Comment: ok, but why it starts with 2? did you try this on your end as well?

Answer (score 5):

Both the loops in the first example starts with 1, so setting the value to i+j = 2.

In the second example it only sets it to i, which starts at 1.